# How to sort an array of 10,000 elements using a quick sort algorithm

Tags: sorting, quicksort

I hate to just post a question regarding homework, but I am having a lot of trouble as to what they are trying to ask from me. I am not asking you to solve my homework problem, only to guide me as to the first steps I should take because I don't know where to begin on this. I read the part of the chapter about quick sort and sort of grasp it and watched a video on it too.

Here's the homework problem:

Sort an array of 10,000 elements using the quick sort algorithm as follows:

a. Sort the array using pivot as the middle element of the array.

b. Sort the array using pivot as the median of the first, last, and middle elements of the array.

c. Sort the array using pivot as the middle element of the array. How- ever, when the size of any sublist reduces to less than 20, sort the sublist using an insertion sort.

d. Sort the array using pivot as the median of the first, last, and middle elements of the array. When the size of any sublist reduces to less than 20, sort the sublist using an insertion sort.

e. Calculate and print the CPU time for each of the preceding four steps.

I'm having trouble understanding - is this going to be one whole function that contains these four steps, or four different functions each doing each step? I get what it means by step a in using pivot as middle element of array (Let's say you have 10 array elements and the middle would be element #4) but I don't get what it means by "sort the array using pivot as the median of the first, last, and middle elements of the array"

I need insight into the inner workings of quick sort and what this book is asking from me.

Comment: 4 variations on the quicksort algorithm (a to d) and compare the timings (e).

Comment: *"one whole function that contains these four steps, or four different functions"* Probably 4 different functions. But nothing stops you from using a single function instead, with an additional parameter that determines which algorithm should be used.

Comment: Median=middle. Given 3 values, sort them and select the middle one.

Comment: This could be one source file with conditional compile statements (#if ... #elif ... #else ...  #endif). For b and d, use two (if ... / swap ...) to sort first, middle, last, so that the median ends up as the middle element. A single function that includes both insertion sort and quick sort could be used. Middle element for pivot suggests [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Middle element could be swapped with first or last and used as pivot for [Lomuto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme), but I don't know if this would be accepted.

Comment: Continuing, calculating cpu time for sorting 10,000 elements is going to be a very small number. You'll need access to a high frequency timer. You didn't mention what programming language is being used or the operating system.